# Simply-connected complex manifolds are symplectic

Tags: reference-request, complex-geometry, geometric-topology, symplectic-geometry

Could you suggest a reference for the proof of the following fact:

> Complex surfaces with trivial fundamental group are symplectic.

UPD:
Once again I found my own question by googling the conditions on when complex surfaces have symplectic structure so it is unfortunate that this question is closed. Maybe I briefly explain why I care about this to reopen.

I'm interested in classification of symplectic 4-manifolds. Many natural examples of 4-manifolds are complex surfaces, so it is important for me to know which of them have symplectic structure.

UPD2: Thanks to Michael's kind comment and explanation, I'd like to add one more detail about what I tried.

I know how to show that concrete manifolds are symplectic by writing down explicitly the symplectic form. Also, I know that algebraic, projective manifolds can be endowed with symplectic structure by restricting Fubini-Studi on $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^n$. But the general statement, I didn't have a faintest idea and googling wasn't helpful at that time.

Comment: Where did you see this claimed? The statement is false.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Could it be that the author implicitly assumes the dimension 4?

Comment: The statement is true in that case, so possibly.

Comment: Now that I think about it, your question in its current form lacks context. Would you mind editing it to include where you saw this claim. Otherwise it may be closed.

Comment: I'm tempted to say that I found it this question being closed very weird. Isn't it a very natural question "which complex manifolds are symplectic"? Do you need to explain why you are curious about "when topological manifolds are smooth" or "when manifolds admit CW structure"?
I'm not intended to be rude, maybe I must read the stackexchange rules more carefully, yes.

Comment: I find the question to be interesting, but you didn't provide any context for the (incorrect) statement. You didn't indicate where it came from or what you had done in an effort to find a reference for it. Had you done either of those things, the question probably wouldn't have been closed. I personally think of asking a question here like asking a person in real life (say, a lecturer or advisor). I don't want them to think I haven't tried to answer it myself before asking them. Providing context assures the users here that you have tried to answer your own question but were unsuccessful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As I pointed out in the comments above, the statement is not true. For example, [Calabi-Eckmann manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calabi%E2%80%93Eckmann_manifold) are complex manifolds which are diffeomorphic to $S^{2m-1}\times S^{2n-1}$ where $m, n > 1$. They are simply connected, but they can't be symplectic as $b_2 = 0$. Note that such manifolds have complex dimension $m + n - 1 \geq 3$. On the other hand, if $X$ is a simply connected complex manifold of complex dimension $2$, then it is necessarily symplectic. To show this, first note that as $X$ is simply connected, it is in particular connected. We must now consider the compact and non-compact cases separately.

Suppose $X$ is compact. If $\pi_1(X) = 0$, then $b_1(X) = 0$. A connected compact complex surface with even first Betti number admits a Kähler metric, and is therefore symplectic. This statement was originally conjectured by Kodaira, and was later proved using the classification of compact complex surfaces, with the final case of K3 surfaces completed by Siu in the paper [*Every K3 surface is Kähler*](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01393829). Later, a proof which does not rely on the classification was found independently by Buchdahl and Lamari, see [*On compact Kähler surfaces*](http://www.numdam.org/item/AIF_1999__49_1_287_0/) and [*Courants kählériens et surfaces compactes*](https://aif.centre-mersenne.org/item/AIF_1999__49_1_263_0/) respectively. For a textbook reference, see Chapter IV, Theorem 3.1 of *Compact Complex Surfaces* by Barth, Hulek, Peters, and Van de Ven.

Suppose $X$ is non-compact (note, $X$ is connected and has no boundary, so $X$ is open). Gromov used the h-principle to show that an open manifold admits a symplectic form if and only if it admits an almost complex structure. See 4.3.2 of [*Stable Mappings of Foliations into Manifolds*](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1070/IM1969v003n04ABEH000796) by Gromov, also Example 3 in [*Lectures on the Theorem of Gromov*](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BFb0068900.pdf) by Haefliger. Note that we didn't use the simply connected assumption here (only connectedness to ensure $X$ is open). One can show that an open four-manifold admits a symplectic form if and only if it is orientable!

We can summarise the above as follows:

> Let $X$ be a connected complex surface.
>
> - If $X$ is compact, then $X$ admits a symplectic form if and only if $b_1(X)$ is even.
> - If $X$ is non-compact, then $X$ admits a symplectic form.

Finally, let me just point out that in complex dimension $1$, every complex manifold is Kähler and hence symplectic.

Comment: In last summary, is there something hidden about $b_2\neq 0$? because in first para you write "but they can't be symplectic as $b_2=0$"

Comment: @C.F.G A symplectic form on a compact manifold gives a non-zero cohomology class in $H^2$.

Comment: @C.F.G As Gunnar Þór Magnússon points out, on a closed manifold $M$, the de Rham cohomology class of a symplectic form is a non-zero element of $H^2_{\text{dR}}(M)$ and hence $b_2(M) \neq 0$. On an open manifold, the cohomology class of a symplectic form need not be non-zero. For example, $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ is symplectic for all $n > 0$.

Comment: By way, simply connected implies connected. So the step of reducing to the connected case is not necessary.

Comment: @LeeMosher: Good point. I have edited my answer.